# Conditional variable check using Ansible with failed_when module?

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible task in which I am using variables - `window` and `total_files`. And I am passing these two variable values from the command line:

```
 - name: Check all files
   find: paths=/var/lib/goldy/jobs/processdata/workspace/files
         file_type=file
         age=-{{ window }}m
         age_stamp=mtime
   register: files
   failed_when: files.matched < total_files
```

Here is how I am running:

```
ansible-playbook -e 'host_key_checking=False' -e 'total_files=6' -e 'window=10' abc.yml
```

But somehow my `total_files` variable is not working at all with `failed_when` module. I tried all the combinations I can think of but if I use `"{{ total_files }}"` like this then I am getting warning so that's why I started using `total_files` like this but still it doesn't work. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

```
[WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: files.matched < "{{ total_files }}"
```

Comment: Please read the description of a tag before applying it to a question. The "linux" tag was completely out of place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I am passing these two variable value **from the command line**

So you are passing strings, hence you compare `files.matched` to a string value.

Change to:

```
failed_when: files.matched < total_files | int
```

---

<sup>The warning you posted is irrelevant to the root problem.</sup>